# Can I ask this translation question on the regular site or will it be closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-off-topic, asking-questions, translation

I'm looking for a translation of a small song I've written for my South Korean girlfriend.  It is only a few sentences long.

I have read the help center, which says this site can be used for help with "small translations", but I don't know when a translation becomes too big for this rule.

> You are perfect to me.
>  And you always look so lovely.
>  Nothing matters but you now,
>  because we both love each other and it's nice.
>  You are my paradise.

My main issue here involves trying to make a translation of this small song that rhymes in Korean similarly to how it rhymes in English, but this is by no means a requirement.

## Is this on- or off-topic for this site?

Answer (score 3):

The basic principle is that this site is supposed to be for focused, specific questions about the Korean language. The longer a passage is, the less likely it is that a request to translate it can be written (or read) in that way.

If there's more than one sentence, it would be nice if any question contained the asker's best attempt at doing the translation so far, and a clear explanation of the difficulties that they are having.

If a post comes across as "do this translation for me", then it's more of a request than a question about the language itself.